# Can you install the same downloaded testflight build on multiple devices

Tags: android, testflight

I'm looking for a way to pre-download the apk files for testers so they can install them from my website instead of downloading directly from testflight. The main reason is that we noticed testflight servers to be very slow at times and testers fail to install latest builds. 
I'm not sure how the extra information (user, device) is added to the testflight logs that are sent to the server. Is the apk file modified to include the extra information or is the API simply sending the logs through the testflight app which attaches all the needed info.

Answer (score 0):

At my work we use Team Foundation Server in order to share our app b/w computers. This way all the tester needs to do is have the TFS plugin through eclipse. This is the link for it.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tfs-plug-eclipse#.Umwt1vnlagA

Comment: thanks for advice, but I assume you're not using testflight at all. I would still like to get all the analytic information that testflight offers, just need a way to make something like a "mirror" page for downloads. In our case it's impossible to use anything like eclipse, because our testers are common users, not developers

Comment: Ahh yeah my mistake. Not sure how you'd go about that.